# is there a way in facebook app to detect when user do unlike and unpublish?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, fbml

im developing a app that gives points if user do like and publish / recommend on my app, is there a way to do anti cheat mechnisem so if user like & unlike right after it will not count it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, you want to look at [FB.Event.subscribe](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/fb.event.subscribe/), specifically the edge.remove global event. You might not have to worry about the cheating at all, however, if you were to build an app that people would genuinely want to use as opposed to having to dangle the points carrot in front of them.